# Button not responding to touch

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uibutton

In my application I added a `UIImageview` to a `UIView` and a `UIButton` added to that `UIImageView`. That button is not responding to touch events and the action selector is not called. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `UIImageView` has its `userInteractionEnabled` property set to `NO` by default. Set it to `YES`.

Comment: This is another brainless inconsistency in UIKit, by the way. It's intentional, but it's more confusing than good.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have IBAction attached to your button. and then check if it has user interaction enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIIMageView *image;
image.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

firstly you add imageview then add button then button is working properly like this code

```
 UIView *AddView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 0, 100, 100)];
 UIImageView *imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];


                UIButton *btnRemove = [[UIButton alloc]init];
                UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"];
                [btnRemove setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [btnRemove addTarget:self
                              action:@selector(btnREmoveAction:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                btnRemove.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 29, 29);

                btnRemove.tag=indexStart;

                [AddView addSubview:imgview]; // add the imageview
                [AddView addSubview:btnRemove];  // add the button
```